# Silverlight in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to connect silverlight or silverlight tools to visual studio? Everything i download says.. Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer Express 2010 or Visual Phone Developer Express 2010 that matches the language version of Silverlight Tools 4 must be installed before installation of Silverlight Tools can continue.  Silverlight Tools is available in other languages at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177432.

The Visual Web Developer feature for Visual Studio 2010 must be installed before installation can continue.
But any tools i try and download say they are unsuitable. Does silverlight 4 or 5 not work with visual studios 2013, has anyone tried this and got it working?

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio 2012 and 2013 comes with Silverlight 5 by Default,

You can create projects with Silverlight directly in Visual Studio 2012 RC. For more Visual Studio 2013 RC compatibility issues please refer to:

[Visual studio 2013 compatability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)

Comment: it doesnt have all the features though

Comment: what feature you want ?